# React multiple inputs onChange into a single array

Tags: reactjs

I have a state that is an array in component A. I then have a component B (whose props are component's A state) in which a number of inputs (type text) are generated based on the state of A. Say 3, then I have 3 input type texts, they are wrapped in a different component and in a div. I am wondering whether I can somehow `onChange` get a value of all three and add it to the array in component A? Order does not matter. Perhaps there is something like get the children of this div container and then map all of their values `onChange` into an array and set the state? Something like that

Edit:

So I have written this, I can see that names are right, but I am getting this error: "Warning: this synthetic event is reused for performance reasons. If you are seeing this you are accessing property target on released ... blah blah". Why do I have a feeling that my setState is not pure. OK, I am taking a break...

```
  onMultipleChange(e) {
        console.log(e.target.name);
        this.setState((prevState, props) => {
            let publicKeys = {...prevState.publicKeys, [e.target.name]: e.target.value};
            return {...prevState, publicKeys}
        }, console.log(this.state));
    }
```

Set the refs like this dynamically:

```
refSetter = (ix) => (ref) => { this._refs[ix] = ref; };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Warning**: This is a pretty naive approach, and obviously feels hacky, but works nonetheless, and is legal. I'm sure there's a better approach that doesn't rely on `refs`.

**Example**: https://codesandbox.io/s/002o3275jl

**Component A**

```
class ComponentA extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      vals: []
    }
    this._refs = {};
  }

  onChange = () => {
    this.setState({
      vals: Object
        .keys(this._refs)
        .map(key => 
          this._refs[key] && 
          this._refs[key].value
        )
     });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        All Vals: {this.state.vals.join(', ')}
        <ComponentB _ref={ref => this._refs['b'] = ref} onChange={this.onChange} />
        <ComponentC _ref={ref => this._refs['c'] = ref} onChange={this.onChange} />
        <ComponentD _ref={ref => this._refs['d'] = ref} onChange={this.onChange} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

**Child Components**

```
const ComponentB = ({_ref, onChange}) => (
  <input ref={_ref} onChange={onChange} type="text" />
);

const ComponentC = ({ _ref,  onChange }) => (
  <input ref={_ref} onChange={onChange} type="text" />
);

const ComponentD = ({ _ref,  onChange }) => (
  <input ref={_ref} onChange={onChange} type="text" />
);
```

Comment: hmm. problem is, I don't have scope to this._refs, as the children are created in a different component, I think I would need to create an index tracker and update it's index or something

Comment: but if I create a function and bind it in the parent component and pass it to component children, they actually have indices, but then the ref function would have to accept to arguments, ref and index.

Comment: hmm not ideal because the user can select 3, then he would get 3 components and then he selects less: 1, but the parent still preserves the keys of 2 and 3

Answer (score 1):

I built up on @lux's answer (by that I mean that I literally took his example and tinkered with it) and came up with an alternative that doesn't involve refs.

Just recently I learned that React's SyntheticEvent (which is reused every time) **can be persisted**, which means that it's taken out of the event pool, allowing you to keep the reference even if other events are fired. This is what I ended up with:

```
class ComponentA extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      vals: [
        {
          name: "ComponentB",
          value: ""
        },
        {
          name: "ComponentC",
          value: ""
        },
        {
          name: "ComponentD",
          value: ""
        },
      ]
    }
  }

  onChange = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.persist();
    this.handleMultipleChanges(e);
  }

  handleMultipleChanges = e => {
    let currentInput = this.state.vals.find(val => val.name === e.target.name);
    currentInput.value = e.target.value;
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      ...prevState,
      vals: prevState.vals.map(val => val.name === currentInput.name ? currentInput : val)
    }));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div style={styles}>
        AllVals: {this.state.vals.map(val => val.value).join(", ")}
        <div><ComponentB name="ComponentB" onChange={this.onChange} /></div>
        <div><ComponentC name="ComponentC" onChange={this.onChange} /></div>
        <div><ComponentD name="ComponentD" onChange={this.onChange} /></div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const ComponentB = ({name, onChange}) => (
  <input name={name} onChange={onChange} type="text" />
);

const ComponentC = ({name, onChange }) => (
  <input name={name} onChange={onChange} type="text" />
);

const ComponentD = ({name, onChange }) => (
  <input name={name} onChange={onChange} type="text" />
);
```

**EDIT**

This is a (pretty basic) variant to add inputs dynamically via a number input, as this was OP's use case:

```
class ComponentA extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      inputNumber: 0,
      vals: []
    }
  }

  onChange = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.persist();
    this.handleMultipleChanges(e);
  }

  handleMultipleChanges = e => {
    let currentInput = this.state.vals.find(val => val.name === e.target.name);
    if (!currentInput) {
      currentInput = {
        name: e.target.name,
        value: e.target.value
      }
      this.setState({vals: this.state.vals.concat(currentInput)});
    } else {
      currentInput.value = e.target.value;
      this.setState(prevState => ({
        ...prevState,
        vals: prevState.vals.map(val => val.name === currentInput.name ? currentInput : val)
      }));
    }
  }

  createInputs = e => {
    const {inputNumber} = this.state;
    const vals = [];

    for (let i = 0; i<inputNumber; i++) {
      vals[i] = {name: "input"+i, value:""};
    }

    this.setState({vals});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        AllVals: {this.state.vals.map(val => val.value).join(", ")}
        <div>
        <input type="number" onChange={e => this.setState({inputNumber: e.target.value})} />
        <button onClick={this.createInputs}>Make Inputs</button>
        </div>
        {this.state.vals.map(
          val => <div><input name={val.name} value={val.value} onChange={this.onChange} /></div>
        )}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: problem is, i do not know beforehand how many components I will have, the user selects that through a number on the front-end

Comment: Well, this was a proof of concept just to show the alternative to refs, because I think the `persist()` method on react's event is kind of obscure (I certainly didn't know about it). I'm editing the answer for adding inputs dynamically